# Is there any way in Scala spark to transforming this dataframe into this?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Transformation of Dataframe

```
Col A || date1     || Value1 || Value2   || Date2

  11  ||2002-08-14 || 44.234 || 485.5975 ||2002-05-30

  11  ||2003-02-14 || 52.699 || 485.5975 ||2002-05-30

  11  ||2003-05-15 || 32.484 || 485.5975 ||2002-05-30

  11  ||2003-08-14 || 39.797 || 817.2205 ||2003-05-30

  11  ||2004-02-14 || 36.114 || 817.2205 ||2003-05-30

  11  ||2004-05-15 || 41.137 || 817.2205 ||2003-05-30
```

and transform into the following:

```
Col A || date1     || Value1 || Value2   || Date2     || Required

  11  ||2002-08-14 || 44.234 || 485.5975 ||2002-05-30 || 44.234+485.5975

  11  ||2003-02-14 || 52.699 || 485.5975 ||2002-05-30 || 52.699+44.234+485.5975

  11  ||2003-05-15 || 32.484 || 485.5975 ||2002-05-30 || 32.484+52.699+44.234+485.5975

  11  ||2003-08-14 || 39.797 || 817.2205 ||2003-05-30 || 39.797+817.2205

  11  ||2004-02-14 || 36.114 || 817.2205 ||2003-05-30 || 36.114+39.797+817.2205

  11  ||2004-05-15 || 41.137 || 817.2205 ||2003-05-30 || 41.137+36.114+39.797+817.2205
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate "Required" column. What exactly its value should be. Also could you share the code/approach whatever you have done s far.

Comment: Basically Required Columns will be the summation of value2 and list of value1 which has same Date2 and whose Date1 is less or equal to current Date1, I tried to right Spark Sql queries and also tried to groupBy but their is no common Id for doing that, trying to create a common Id will lead to solution.

Comment: @tastelesswine, isn't it group by "Value2" ? Your grouping logic seems to be not fitting to second group for "Required" column.

Comment: @tastelesswine please check my answer, please let me know in case any concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

scala> df.show(false)
+-----+----------+------+--------+----------+
|Col A|date1     |Value1|Value2  |Date2     |
+-----+----------+------+--------+----------+
|11   |2002-08-14|44.234|485.5975|2002-05-30|
|11   |2003-02-14|52.699|485.5975|2002-05-30|
|11   |2003-05-15|32.484|485.5975|2002-05-30|
|11   |2003-08-14|39.797|817.2205|2003-05-30|
|11   |2004-02-14|36.114|817.2205|2003-05-30|
|11   |2004-05-15|41.137|817.2205|2003-05-30|
+-----+----------+------+--------+----------+

scala> val W  = Window.partitionBy("Col A", "Date2").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("sumListValue1", sum(col("value1")).over(W).cast("Decimal(14,2)"))

scala> df1.show()
+-----+----------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|Col A|     date1|Value1|  Value2|     Date2|sumListValue1|
+-----+----------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|   11|2003-08-14|39.797|817.2205|2003-05-30|        39.80|
|   11|2004-02-14|36.114|817.2205|2003-05-30|        75.91|
|   11|2004-05-15|41.137|817.2205|2003-05-30|       117.05|
|   11|2002-08-14|44.234|485.5975|2002-05-30|        44.23|
|   11|2003-02-14|52.699|485.5975|2002-05-30|        96.93|
|   11|2003-05-15|32.484|485.5975|2002-05-30|       129.42|
+-----+----------+------+--------+----------+-------------+


scala> df1.withColumn("Required", col("sumListValue1") + col("Value2")).drop("sumListValue1").show()
+-----+----------+------+--------+----------+--------+
|Col A|     date1|Value1|  Value2|     Date2|Required|
+-----+----------+------+--------+----------+--------+
|   11|2003-08-14|39.797|817.2205|2003-05-30|857.0205|
|   11|2004-02-14|36.114|817.2205|2003-05-30|893.1305|
|   11|2004-05-15|41.137|817.2205|2003-05-30|934.2705|
|   11|2002-08-14|44.234|485.5975|2002-05-30|529.8275|
|   11|2003-02-14|52.699|485.5975|2002-05-30|582.5275|
|   11|2003-05-15|32.484|485.5975|2002-05-30|615.0175|
+-----+----------+------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Your grouping logic is not very clear but you can adjust following logic for grouping if needed. I took an assumption that Value2 is a candidate of grouping for this sample dataset.

Here is sample code to achieve output, if you want to sum value then can change aggregation accordingly.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val inDF = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("one.csv")

val w = Window.partitionBy(col("Value2")).orderBy(desc("idx"))

val rowNumWindow = Window.partitionBy(col("Value2")).orderBy("Date2")
val outDF =  inDF.withColumn("idx", row_number() over rowNumWindow).
   withColumn("item_list", collect_list(col("Value1")) over w).
   withColumn("Required",concat_ws("+",col("item_list"),col("Value2"))) 



outDF.select("ColA","date1","Value1","Value2","Date2","Required").show(10,false)


root
 |-- ColA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Value1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Value2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date2: string (nullable = true)

|ColA|date1     |Value1|Value2  |Date2     |
+----+----------+------+--------+----------+
|11  |2002-08-14|44.234|485.5975|2002-05-30|
|11  |2003-02-14|52.699|485.5975|2002-05-30|
|11  |2003-05-15|32.484|485.5975|2002-05-30|
|11  |2003-08-14|39.797|817.2205|2003-05-30|
|11  |2004-02-14|36.114|817.2205|2003-05-30|
|11  |2004-05-15|41.137|817.2205|2003-05-30|
+----+----------+------+--------+----------+
```

Output to show same as in Question:

```
+----+----------+------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
|ColA|date1     |Value1|Value2  |Date2     |Required                     |
+----+----------+------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
|11  |2004-05-15|41.137|817.2205|2003-05-30|41.137+817.2205              |
|11  |2004-02-14|36.114|817.2205|2003-05-30|41.137+36.114+817.2205       |
|11  |2003-08-14|39.797|817.2205|2003-05-30|41.137+36.114+39.797+817.2205|
|11  |2003-05-15|32.484|485.5975|2002-05-30|32.484+485.5975              |
|11  |2003-02-14|52.699|485.5975|2002-05-30|32.484+52.699+485.5975       |
|11  |2002-08-14|44.234|485.5975|2002-05-30|32.484+52.699+44.234+485.5975|
+----+----------+------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

If you want to do sum then you can do this:

```
val outDF =  inDF.withColumn("idx", row_number() over rowNumWindow).
 withColumn("item_list", sum(col("Value1")) over w).
 withColumn("Required",(col("item_list")+col("Value2")))
outDF.select("ColA","date1","Value1","Value2","Date2","Required").show(10,false)
```

Output :

```
+----+----------+------+--------+----------+-----------------+
|ColA|date1     |Value1|Value2  |Date2     |Required         |
+----+----------+------+--------+----------+-----------------+
|11  |2004-05-15|41.137|817.2205|2003-05-30|858.3575000000001|
|11  |2004-02-14|36.114|817.2205|2003-05-30|894.4715         |
|11  |2003-08-14|39.797|817.2205|2003-05-30|934.2685         |
|11  |2003-05-15|32.484|485.5975|2002-05-30|518.0815         |
|11  |2003-02-14|52.699|485.5975|2002-05-30|570.7805000000001|
|11  |2002-08-14|44.234|485.5975|2002-05-30|615.0145         |
+----+----------+------+--------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: monotonically_increasing_id is not a good to use in code, instead of this row_number should be use with window.

Comment: @Nikk Sure, I will update my answer with row_number